# Peak-Over-Threshold for multiple weather stations in the US

Tags: hypothesis-testing, extreme-value, climate, meteorology

I'm trying to make an Extreme Value Analysis (EVA) of maximum and minimum temperature data from all over the US and try to fit a Generalised Pareto Distribution (GPD) according to theory after applying the Peak-Over-Threshold method.

I'm using an agreed threshold at the 95th percentile of the daily pooled data into a month.

I am trying to aggregate all the weather observations in order to accumulate as much tail events as possible to be able to perform a EVA analysis since the scarcity of extreme events in a single month for a single place is really scarce.

My assumption for aggregating the data is that all weather stations have a part of their tails that is governed by the same dynamic (that is, climate change). This single process is identified at the conditional tail risk. I allow for unconditional tail risk in the shape parameter of a potential GDP, ai/λt, being ai the unconditional risk for each weather station (their own characteristics due to geographical location,etc.) and λt being the time-varying tail risk that would represent this climate change.

I would estimate this $λ_t$ by Hill, MLM or Dekkers-Einmahl,De Haan estimator, I still need to decide.

The thing is, to obtain this GPD, my data need to fulfill independence and identically distributed  data. I am really struggling to make my data independent, and my first trials for doing a declustering have been in vain.

Do you know any feasible way of doing it? Also, I could do a block maxima and obtain a Generalised Extreme Value distribution and still calculate the shape parameter, however I still don't know how.

Do you know how I could try and do the declustering and if not, how could I do the block maxima?

I've seen that most EVA analysis are just from single places/weather stations but not for multiple places at the same time ...

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Weather data is often in the form of daily highs and lows $H_{p,y,d}$ and $L_{p,y,d}$ for a place $p$ in the year $y$ on day $d$ of that year. Can you describe what you want to model in those terms? Among other things. I am not sure from which populations the 95th percentiles are taken.